# Wordpress visual editor changes quoted code into image

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I want to display on my wordpress page some HTML and JavaScript code. I enclose it in [code] tags and in text editor it works fine. But only if I switch to visual editor it spoils me this quoted code and converts JavaScript code to image:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODl....." data-wp-preserve="%3Cscript%...
```

This HTML + JavaScript is not to be executed on page but to be displayed.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the all of the code you're putting in, and all of the code it's outputting?

Comment: Eventually my solution was to disable visual editor and add to the text editor several quick tags.